# Add element to a dictionary by input Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary like this using user's input:

```
a = {
'1': {'2': 2, '3': 5, '4': 1},
'2': {'1': 2, '3': 2, '4':4},
'3': {'1': 5, '2':2},
'4': {'1': 1, '2': 4, '5':3}, 
'5': {'4':3}}
```

For example, in input I have to write "2 2 3 5 4 1" and these values goes to index N. 1 "{'1': {'2': 2, '3': 5, '4': 1}"

I've been trying to do this for a while but I couldn't succeed.
I've tried to use a for and split the list in many arguments but still I have concluded nothing.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Do you need to better define your goal, will the input be a string with all the values or how the user types you adding to the dictionary?

This problem is a business problem.

Comment: Read again your syntax please.

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an element to dict using this code:

```
dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
dict[index] = [7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `str.split` and utilise `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

input_str = '2 2 3 5 4 1'

def zipper(mystr):
    split = mystr.split()
    return zip(islice(split, 0, None, 2), islice(split, 1, None, 2))

d = {}
d['1'] = dict({k: int(v) for k, v in zipper(input_str)})

# {'1': {'2': 2, '3': 5, '4': 1}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And if I want the keys to be integer numbers? Like this {'1': {'2': 2, '3': 5, '4': 1} and not this {'1': {'2': '2', '3': '5', '4': '1'}

Answer (score 0):

Use `input` to get the data, and `split` to break it at spaces:

```
response = input('Enter digits separated by spaces').split()
```

Now a loop that continues until the user doesn't provide any more input:

```
while response:
    payload = response[:-1]   # all but the last number
    index = response[-1]      # this is your dictionary key
    # Now count the repetitions in the user's input and assign to a[index]
    a[index] = {k: payload.count(k) for k in payload}  
    # And ask for more input
    response = input('Enter more digits (press Enter to finish)').split()
```

Then display your results:

```
print(a)
```